# Extract values form vector according the order of another vector in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors `x` and `w`. I want to extract the elements of vector `x` according to order of `w` and the lengths `z`. How can I do this easier and faster in R?

```
     x = c(1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 2.4, 5.3, 6.6, 7.8)
     w = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6)
     z = 5
     m = matrix(c(x[w], w), ncol=2)
     > m
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]  1.3    1
    [2,]  1.5    2
    [3,]  1.6    3
    [4,]  5.3    5
    [5,]  7.8    7
    [6,]  2.4    4
    [7,]  6.6    6

     f = m[1:z,1]
     > f
   [1] 1.3 1.5 1.6 5.3 7.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
 x[w[1:z]]
[1] 1.3 1.5 1.6 5.3 7.8
```